# Node file system

Tags: node.js

Can something explain how in `res.write(html)`, the html parameter maps to `./index.html`?

Here is the code. Am I not understanding how callback functions work?

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var host = 'localhost';
var port = '8888';

fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, html){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
        res.StatusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.write(html);
        res.end();
    });

    server.listen(port, host, function(){
        console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This code says to run `fs.readFile('./index.html', ...)` to get the file './index.html' into memory.  When the file is done being read into memory, call the callback that you passed it and put the contents into the function parameter you named `html`.  At any point inside that callback function, you can refer to the `html` function parameter and it will contain the contents of the './index.html' file that was read from disk.

Then after that, create your server and define a request handler callback for it that will be called each time an incoming request is received by your web server. 
That callback will then send the data in that `html` parameter as the response to that incoming request.

Then, start that server.

---

It's kind of an odd way to write things, but there's nothing technically wrong with it.

Note that the `http.serverServer()` callback is nested inside the other callback.  In Javascript, you have access to not only your own local parameters and local variables, but also the parameters and local variables of any parent functions that you are nested inside of.

---

> Am I not understanding how callback functions work?

I don't know what you do and don't understand about callback functions.  In both the `fs.readFile()` and `http.createServer()` case, these are callbacks that will be called sometime in the future when some operation completes.  In the `fs.readFile()` case, it's callback is called when the file contents have been entirely read into memory.  In the `http.createserver()` case, the callback is called whenever any incoming request is received by the web server.